# Content DB property "WarningSiteCount" does not work

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-database

I'd like to use the "`WarningSiteCount`" property to receive information when sites warning number has reached.

Unfortunately, I do not receive emails (I'm putting my account as the primary site administrator). The property does not work as it is described in this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spcontentdatabase.warningsitecount.aspx)

I can add that "`MaximumSiteCount`" works as expected - I'm not able to create another site when the limit number has reached.

Did anybody has the same problem and can help me?

Answer (score 0):

In the event viewer, one warning event with the ID 6593 triggered when the site collection count exceed the warning site count. In actually, the event ID 6593 triggered only on the server hosting the Central Admin but not on the other servers of the farm.

So it’s by default that we are not received notification from the SharePoint. There is only a warning in the event viewer and ULS log.

Comment: are you sure? what about "...and the owner of the site collection is notified."?